# jsp jdbc data access layer design

Tags: java, design-patterns, jsp

Hi:
I have a question about how to design and map object class in java with database(sql).

For example, if I have Customer and Order Class which match with Customer and Order Table in database. If I need the Customer and Order information separately, I simply use SQL query to fetch the information from database table and put them into List and List, and display in front end application.
What if I need to display to display both Customer and Order information at the same time?
How do put both Customer and Order object in one single arraylist?

If anyone can help me answering this question in either jsp or asp.net, i will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to construct a transfer object which includes the necessary information from both objects, and put the TO into a list.

Check http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/TransferObject.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object for more information on this pattern.

Comment: Thank u for the reply. In asp.net, I usually just dump everything in dataset and display the information. I did find using sql query and dataset are very hard to maintain.  When I learned java, I was taught in jdbc and hibernate, but I still not sure if ORM such as hibernate can handle this situation better

Answer (score 1):

First - don't do this in a jsp. Do it in a regular class invoked by a servlet/controller. Then take a look at some ORM - hibernate, eclipselink. But it might be too complicated for a simple project. Also look at commons-dbutils.